# Markov chain and uniqueness of invariant measure

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider the following part of a proof from Durrett's book where we have a Markov chain $X.$

I am having problems in the last part of the proof where we must have $\nu(x)=\nu(y)\mu_y(x)$ whenever $p^n(x,y)>0.$
Why is this true in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is used here is that if $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x \in S$ and
$\sum_{x \in S} f(x)=\sum_{x \in S} g(x)$, then we must have $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in S$.

Comment: We should also suppose that $\sum_{x \in S}|f(x)| <\infty$ ? (which is the case in the above proof)

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is part of the assumption